# Precision matrix of AR(2) matrix

Tags: stochastic-processes, covariance, vector-auto-regression

I am trying to construct the inverse covariance matrix of an AR(2) process of the form $X_t=\theta_1 X_{t-1}+\theta_2 X_{t-2} + \epsilon_t$ with i.i.d. $\epsilon_i$, $\mathbb{E} \epsilon_i =0$, $\mathbb{E}\epsilon_i\epsilon_j=\sigma^2 \delta_{i,j}$. We assume the process to be stationary.

I have already calculated the variance  $Var(X_t)=\frac{(1-\theta_2)\sigma^2}{(1+\theta_2)((1-\theta_2)^2-\theta_1^2)}$ and the autocorrelation coefficients $\rho_1=\frac{\mathbb{E}X_t x_{t-1}}{Var(X_t)}=\frac{\theta_1}{1-\theta_2}$, $\rho_2=\frac{\mathbb{E}X_t x_{t-2}}{Var(X_t)}=\theta_2+\frac{\theta_1^2}{1-\theta_2}$ and $\rho_s=\theta_1 \rho_{s-1}+\theta_2 \rho_{s-2}$ for $s>2$.

How do I now proceed to construct the inverse covariance matrix? I tried to calculate it analytically but it did not work out.

EDIT: For fix $T$ I am looking for the inverse matrix of the covariance matrix $\Phi$ with entries $\Phi_{ij}=Cov(X_i,X_j)$, $i, j = 1,\dots,T$. The entries of this covariance matrix are already given by the autocorrelation coefficients above since the process is assumed to be stationary.

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Can you please define the covariance matrix you are looking for? I'm not quite sure what variables make up its dimensions from your description. Also, why do you believe that inverse covariance would have a closed-form analytic expression?

Comment: @AleksejsFomins I have specified the covariance matrix in my question. I know that the inverse covariance matrix has a simple form since I have found it in a book but I have no idea how to calculate it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll think about it for a bit

Comment: @AleksejsFomins There are certain conditions for $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ under which the process is stationary and I think that stationarity in particular implies that $\mathbb{E} X_t^2$ does not depend on $t$. I basically followed the calculations given under the following link: https://www.uni-kassel.de/fb07/fileadmin/datas/fb07/5-Institute/IVWL/Kosfeld/lehre/zeitreihen/AR-Modelle.pdf Unfortunately, the source is German but they get the same result like I have.

Comment: No worries, I think I get it now. You wait until the probability distribution of $X_t$ is the same as for $X_{t-1}$. And you need the covariance for some $X_t$ that is not at the start of the experiment, but somewhere far in the future when initial conditions have been long forgotten. Would it be difficult for you to present your proof for variances and covariances if it is not too long? For now, I will continue by assuming that your equations for the correlation matrix are correct

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so this is not the full solution, but I will present how to get the explicit form for $\Phi$, maybe somebody figures out how to invert it. So, according to the above notation, $\Phi_{ij} = \rho_{|i-j|}$, where $\rho_0 = 1$ and $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ are specified in the question

We will now solve the recurrence relation $\rho_s = \theta_1 \rho_{s-1} + \theta_2 \rho_{s-2}$ with help of generating functions

Define $G(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\rho_ix^i$, then use recurrence relation

$G(x)
= \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\rho_{i+1} x^i 
= \rho_1 + x \rho_2 + \sum_{i=2}^{\infty}x^i \theta_1\rho_{i} + \sum_{i=2}^{\infty}x^i \theta_2 \rho_{i-1}
= \rho_1 + x(\rho_2-\theta_1\rho_1) + x \theta_1 G(x) + x^2 \theta_2 G(x)
$

Let $c_1 = \rho_2-\theta_1\rho_1 = \theta_2$. Solving for $G(x)$, we get

$$G(x)
= \frac{\rho_1 + x c_1}{1 - \theta_1x-\theta_2x^2}
= \frac{\rho_1 + x c_1}{-\theta_2 (x-k_1)(x-k_2)}
= \frac{\rho_1 + x c_1}{\theta_2 (k_1 - k_2)}(\frac{1}{x-k_2} - \frac{1}{x-k_1})
= \frac{\rho_1 + x c_1}{\theta_2 (k_1 - k_2)}(\frac{1}{k_1}\frac{1}{1-\frac{x}{k_1}} -\frac{1}{k_2}\frac{1}{1-\frac{x}{k_2}})
$$

Here we have factored the quadratic equation, resulting in solutions $k_{1,2} = \frac{1}{2 \theta_2}(-\theta_1 \pm \sqrt{\theta_1^2 + 4 \theta_2})$

Now we substitute the series $\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+...$

$$G(x)
= \frac{\rho_1 + x c_1}{\theta_2 (k_1 - k_2)} (\frac{1}{k_1}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^i}{k_1^i} - \frac{1}{k_2}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^i}{k_2^i})
= (\rho_1 + c_1 x) \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_ix^i
$$
Where
$$a_i = \frac{1}{\theta_2(k_1-k_2)}(\frac{1}{k_1^{i+1}} - \frac{1}{k_2^{i+1}})$$

Finally,
$$\rho_{i+1} = \rho_1 a_i + c_1 a_{i-1} = \rho_1 a_i + \theta_2 a_{i-1}$$

So the next step is to try to simplify the explicit form of $\Phi_{ij}$ to see if it is somehow invertible. I'm sure there probably is a faster way to do this, if one somehow exploits some known symmetry of the matrix, but that's beyond me atm